# Use OkHttp to upload file but occur java.lang.IllegalStateException : closed at okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:44)

Tags: android, file-upload, okhttp

The issue is what the title said. It only occur sometimes and some phone. Hear is the log that I caught.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException
closed
okio.RealBufferedSink.write(RealBufferedSink.java:44)
okio.ForwardingSink.write(ForwardingSink.java:35)
com.******.******.network.UploadRequestBody$1.write(UploadRequestBody.java:75)
okio.RealBufferedSink.emitCompleteSegments(RealBufferedSink.java:176)
okio.RealBufferedSink.writeAll(RealBufferedSink.java:104)
com.squareup.okhttp.RequestBody$3.writeTo(RequestBody.java:118)
com.squareup.okhttp.MultipartBuilder$MultipartRequestBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBuilder.java:277)
com.squareup.okhttp.MultipartBuilder$MultipartRequestBody.writeTo(MultipartBuilder.java:297)
com.******.******.network.UploadRequestBody.writeTo(UploadRequestBody.java:59)
com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine$NetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(HttpEngine.java:718)
com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:576)
com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:287)
com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:243)
com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:205)
com.squareup.okhttp.Call.access$100(Call.java:35)
com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:171)
com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
```

Would you mind helping me and telling how to avoid it?

Comment: Looks like a bug. What version of OkHttp are you using?

Comment: Are you closing the stream that you're writing to?

Comment: I used 2.7.5 and I haven't call the close function. :(

Answer (score 1):

I find this at github [issue](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/1240)

You can only call `response.body().string()` once.